# Google map API web service from Google Tutorial does not work for me.

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am new to Google Map API , and I just try to search for hospitals near my place using the given URL below from the Google MAP API tutorial.

Plus from my Google console, I have Google MAP API version 2 and 3 turn on, and places API turn on.

I enter this URL from the tutorial into my browser and press return

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=37.722434,-121.465902&radius=10000&types=hospitals&sensor=false&key=mykey

where mykey is the Google API key I got from Google console,

and I got this message

REQUEST DENIED

I am confused. I don't know what I am missing. I followed the Google tutorial and I got the Google API key from the Google console. I wonder if there is any other api key out there that I did not know. Please help me if you could.

Thanks so much in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

If you have an account with Google, make sure the location you're making the request from is added to your list of allowed domains. That is the common issue when using Google Maps. Other than that your key could be wrong and/or you need to create an encrypted key.

Comment: Hello, I have a google account and that 's what I added https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml for accept this request from a referer web site but it does not work. I also regenerate my API key. But nothing works. I still got request denied. Please help if you could . Many Thanks!!!